# How to disable IntelliJ triggering build when I change pom.xml and makes editing a bad user experience?

Tags: intellij-idea

Whenever I need to edit pom.xml in IntelliJ it triggers rebuild/validation/sync event and grabs the focus from the editor. This way is pretty annoying working with pom.xml files with IntelliJ.

Pom.xml files are the place where it is super annoying. I just can't select a plugin from the list without these events triggered and the focus is taken away from the editor. So I have to hit Ctrl + Space again to get the list, etc.

Is there a way to disable this feature, or it is part of "No save is needed" way of doing things of IntelliJ?

Comment: Have you tried disabling Maven auto imports? Go to File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing and disable "Import Maven projects automatically"

Comment: Thanks for the help! If you write an answer I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to disable auto-build, you should disable Maven auto import in settings.

Go to File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing and disable "Import Maven projects automatically"

Answer (score 1):

In 2022, this setting was renamed and moved. It is now in File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools  and it's called `Reload project after changes in the build scripts`. You might try enabling it with `External changes` checked first. If that's still too annoying, then disable it entirely.